# FlexSlider 2 | sync between the nav and the main slider not working after addslide

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, slider, flexslider

I'm trying to add new slides after the slider is already initialized.

when the slide trigger the "end callback" ( add new slide )

```
jQuery('#main_slider').data('flexslider').addSlide( jQuery( result.html.main ) );
jQuery('#main_slider_nav').data('flexslider').addSlide( jQuery( result.html.thumbnail ) );
jQuery('#main_slider').data('flexslider').resize();
jQuery('#main_slider_nav').data('flexslider').resize();
jQuery('#main_slider').flexslider('next');
```

Work fine .. but -
the problem is when I try to "click" the new nav slider that I just added, its do nothing.
nothing happened.

hope you got my problem and would be able to help me with that.

Thanks !